# No disk visible when installing OS x Mavericks

Tags: macos, mac, reboot

I wiped my Macbook Air and am trying to reinstall the OS. I had Sierra. When I install, there is a message stating I do not have prebooted APFS volumes. But when I try to install OS X Mavericks from internet, it shows no available disks. I do have Mackintosh HD mounted (clean) and created a new untitled drive too as someone recommended. I am a complete rookie in this. No access to something like Genius bar due to lockdown.

Comment: When you [boot into Internet Recovery mode](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+to+Start+Up+a+Mac+in+Internet+Recovery+Mode/119437), before starting the install open `Disk Utility`. Does it show your hard disks?

Comment: Since you’re downgrading, I assume you’re using a bootable USB installer for Mavericks, right? The USB should have an Applications option in the menu bar at the top of the screen; expand that and open Disk Utility. From there you can format the hard disk as “Mac OS Extended” (aka HFS+) and will be able to install the OS.

Comment: Thanks so much for answers. I was rebooting as “internet recovery” and it was offering Mavericks. I kept redoing this process until one time it offered me the option to format hard disk as Mac OS extended - this option was not available before. I have no idea why it appeared on something like tenth try of rebooting with Command+R. Once I did this, it could see the drive. And eventually I upgraded it to BigSur thru App Store - a 6 hr process but so glad it worked! Thank you!!